# Build an .exe file from .py with cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I'm trying to make an executable file from a project on python (setup.py)

```
    import sys
    import xlrd
    import pyodbc
    import tkinter as tk
    import os.path
    from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QDialog
    from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
    from PyQt5 import QtGui
    from tkinter import filedialog
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    base = None    

    PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
    #os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\tcl\tcl8.6'
    #os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\tcl\tk8.6'

    executables = [Executable("Load File.py",
                   base=base,
                   icon="BI Icon.ico")] 

    packages = ["tkinter","pyodbc","PyQt5","datetime","win32api"]

    files = ["BI Icon.ico","Load Excel.ui",
             r"C:\Users\PQ946KK\Documents\Leti\Proyectos\PowerBI\Icon\arrow up load.png",
             os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
             os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')]

    options = {
        'build_exe': {    
            'packages':packages,
            'include_files':files,
        },    
    }

    setup(
        name = "LoadFile BI",
        options = options,
        version = "0.1",
        description = 'Ejecutable de Aplicacion Load File',
        executables = executables
    )
```

Whenever I build, it only makes a few files (As long as I remember it should create more files and folders)

```
    (base) C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Leti\Proyectos\PowerBI>python setup.py build
    running build
    running build_exe
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\Load File.exe
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python36.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\python36.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\VCRUNTIME140.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
    copying C:\Users\PQ946KK\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll

    (base) C:\Users\XXXXXX\Documents\Leti\Proyectos\PowerBI>python setup.py build
```

I've tried reinstalling Python, Anaconda and setting up global variables, no luck still getting the same result and of course the .exe file is not functional. Error message:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

I should also mention that this is the first time I build a file with a separate .ui File.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried to add `encodings` to the `packages` list option?

   ```
   packages = ["tkinter","pyodbc","PyQt5","datetime","win32api","encodings"]
   ```
2. Please also notice that, if you freeze your application with `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1 (current default version) or 5.1.0, you need to include the TCL and TK DLLs into a subdirectory `lib`. You can do that by passing a tuple `(source, destination)` to the corresponding entry of the `include_files` list option:

   ```
   files = ["BI Icon.ico", "Load Excel.ui",
            r"C:\Users\PQ946KK\Documents\Leti\Proyectos\PowerBI\Icon\arrow up load.png",
            (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
            (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'), os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))]
   ```
3. If you build a GUI application (as it seems), you should also modify the definition of `base` as follows in your setup script, before using it in `Executable`:

   ```
   # GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a console application).
   base = None
   if sys.platform == "win32":
       base = "Win32GUI"
   ```
4. Why do you actually use both `tkinter` and `PyQt5`? One should be enough to provide a GUI, shouldn't it? If you do not use `tkinter` in your application (as I guess), you often need to exclude it explicitly in the setup script by means of an `excludes` list option (and of course remove it from the `packages` list and remove the `import tkinter as tk`):

   ```
   packages = ["pyodbc","PyQt5","datetime","win32api"]

   files = ...

   excludes = ['tkinter']

   options = {
       'build_exe': {    
           'packages':packages,
           'include_files':files,
           'excludes':excludes
           },    
       }
   ```

   You might not need any more to provide the TK and TCL DLLs then.
5. Using a separate `.ui` file is not a problem with `cx_Freeze`. You should only make sure that the frozen application looks for the `.ui` file at the right place.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your answer, I've managed to realize there were 3 issues. First of all, some files seemed to be corrupted so I scratch install everything again. Then, the version of PyQt5 was not compatible so I installed a < 5.10 version. Later, I realized that the .ui file didn't move into the .exe folder so I manually moved it and make sure the filename has no spaces. Finally manage to build the project and got tired of fighting with cx_Freeze and make a single file with auto-py-to-exe that includes eel and pyinstaller options in a graphical environment.